# Mensaje en Autocompletar JtextField en java eclipse

Tags: java

alguien me puede ayudar con mi problema por favor.
Tengo un campo de texto al cual tiene la accion de autocompletar al escribir algo sobre el mismo. Mi problema seria como hago para q cuando ingrese otra palabra q no aparezca en el autocompletar me salga un mensaje diciendo q la palabra ingresada no es correcta? Les dejo el codigo

```
public void calle(){

    try{
    TextAutoCompleter completar = new TextAutoCompleter(txtCalle);

    String  SQL = "SELECT nombre FROM calle";

    Statement st = cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);

       while(rs.next())
       {

           completar.addItem(rs.getString("nombre"));

       }


    }
    catch(Exception e) { JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues si el código que ud proporciona funciona con palabras **existentes** en el query, el `ResultSet` lo puede verificar  si está vacío:

```
public void calle(){

   try{
   TextAutoCompleter completar = new TextAutoCompleter(txtCalle);

   String  SQL = "SELECT nombre FROM calle";

   Statement st = cn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);

   if(!rs.next()){
     completar.addItem("Palabra no existe");
     return;
   }

      while(rs.next())
      {

         completar.addItem(rs.getString("nombre"));

      }


      }
     catch(Exception e) { JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);}

}
```

### Edit

Si ud mira su código, está seleccionando siempre **TODO** de su tabla `calle`,
por lo que nunca entraría en la declaración `if`, una mejor implementación sería realizar una búsqueda dependiendo de lo que se esté buscando (que es precisamente lo que ud quiere), es totalmente innecesario e ineficiente extraer toda la información siempre y si no entonces guárdela en un arreglo...

Algo por el estilo:

```
public void calle(String palabra){

  String queryString = "SELECT nombre FROM calle WHERE nombre LIKE ?";
  PreparedStatement ps =  cn.prepareStatement(queryString);
  ps.setString(1,"%"+palabra+"%");

  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

  // resto de código ....

}
```

De ésta forma selecciona lo que contenga la palabra y no TODO, aparte así puede verificar que esté vacío..

Comment: Hola. Gracias por contestar. El codigo esta funcionando bien con palabras existentes. Lo que me dijiste q agregue no me funciona. Sigue sin aparecerme un mensaje cuando ingreso otra palabra q no este en la columna "nombre".

Comment: Ya le agregué a la respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa q te moleste tanto, pero soy novato en esto. Lo que quiero es que en el campo de texto se llenen las los nombres de las calles, pero si el nombre de la calle que ingreso no existe, que me aparezca un mensaje diciendo que no existe esa calle.
Hago lo que me dijiste y me sale el siguiente mensaje: "java.sql.SQLException parameter index out of range (1 number of parameters which is 0)"

Comment: Esa query está bien, debe haber algo mal por haber hecho copy-paste Victor, revise bien su código y las variables